# How to redirect Universal link to app store without showing pop up on Safari browser?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, ios-universal-links

I am using universal link in iOS application. For the universal link I am using of Firebase dynamic link.

Universal link is working fine when app is installed. But when app is not installed then this link is opening in safari.

I am creating dynamic link (Universal link) programatically in Swift.

```
func createDynamicLinkForConsumer(){


        guard let link = URL(string: "https://<Domain-Name>?consumerID=\(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "")&type=consumerReferral") else { return }

        let dynamicLinksDomainURIPrefix = "<appName>.page.link"

        let linkBuilder = DynamicLinkComponents(link: link, domain: dynamicLinksDomainURIPrefix)
        linkBuilder.options?.pathLength = .short
        linkBuilder.iOSParameters = DynamicLinkIOSParameters(bundleID: "<Bundle-ID>")
        linkBuilder.iOSParameters?.appStoreID = "<app-store-id>"
        linkBuilder.androidParameters = DynamicLinkAndroidParameters(packageName: "<android package name>")
        linkBuilder.navigationInfoParameters?.isForcedRedirectEnabled = true


        guard let longDynamicLink = linkBuilder.url else { return }

        print("The long URL is: \(longDynamicLink)")

        self.referralLinkLabel.text = String(describing: longDynamicLink)

        DynamicLinkComponents.shortenURL(longDynamicLink, options: nil) { (url, warnings, error) in

            if url != nil {

                print("Short URL is: \(url)")

                self.referralLinkLabel.text = String(describing: url!)

            }

        }

    }
```

This is the screen which opens after when safari opens the link:

[image]

After tapping on "Open" button of alert box browser opens app store app.

Actually what I would like to do is to redirect and go to the app store, so users can download the app directly. I don't want to this two steps to open app store.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: I am facing the same problem. So, please help me if you are already done with this.

Answer (score 3):

You should first init DynamicLinkNavigationInfoParameters, then set property to true.

```
linkBuilder.navigationInfoParameters = DynamicLinkNavigationInfoParameters()
linkBuilder.navigationInfoParameters?.isForcedRedirectEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can reduce these steps with this check on the dynamic link

[image]

But you should have in mind that you can have a problem with your link in Messanger app and some other apps.

Comment: I am creating that dynamic link programatically and I added parameter "isForcedRedirectEnabled = true". But it is not working. Please check question again, I have edited it.

Comment: you can check in the documentation and this is exactly what you need. Maybe you can update the library with the last version, but still, I think it is better to keep this page.